# Problema al descargar archivo con php

Tags: php7, php5

Tengo ese código php:

```
set_time_limit(3600);

$archivo = $_GET["archivo"];  
$zip = new ZipArchive();  
$filename = "conceptos_basicos_fp.zip";  
$comprimido = "conceptos_basicos_fp.mp4";

if($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true)
{
    $zip->addFile($archivo, $comprimido);
    $zip->close();
}

//Generar Descarga
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename));
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es un comprimir un archivo y enseguida se tiene que descargar ese archivo, el problema es que no descarga correctamente archivos pesados, por ejemplo tengo un video que pesa 185 MB, si lo comprime correctamente pero descarga un archivo dañado, hice la prueba con un video que pesa 71.7 MB y si lo descargo correctamente.

Como puedo solucionar esto??

Answer (score 0):

Investigando por la internet me di cuenta de que el problema viene al manejar archivos pesados y esto es porque **PHP** posee un espacio limitado para hacer `output buffering` por lo que al trabajar así como tengo el código obtenía archivos truncados o vacios.

Para solucionar esto y poder trabajar con cualquier tamaño de archivo agregué la linea de código `ob_end_flush();`

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename));
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
ob_end_flush();
readfile($filename);
```